Snowpark filter function does not work correctly
I am trying to filter a Snowpark df with string value. But end result numbers are nonsense.
my_df = my_df.withColumn("MY_COLUMN", trim(F.col("MY_COLUMN")))

my_df.groupBy(F.col("MY_COLUMN")).count().show() #This gives correct results
print(my_df.filter(F.col("MY_COLUMN").isin('01', '10')).count()) #Total numbers matches too

df1 = my_df.filter(F.col("MY_COLUMN") == "01") #this counts never matches
df2 = my_df.filter(F.col("MY_COLUMN") == "10")` #this counts never matches

I had tried a lot of different things: trim, withcolumn, cast, in, filter, functions.col...
Also pretty sure about it has not have nulls or another data type on that column.
Any thoughts? Can it be related something like cache?
(I can not share exact dataset because of the privacy, sorry for that)
